# Why is there a memory leak in this JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

```
function addHandler( ) 
{
    var el = document.getElementById('el');

    el.onclick = function( ) 
    {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    };
}
```

Why is there a leak in the JavaScript block above?

Comment: Why do you think there is a memory leak in the first place?

Comment: Have you used some tools like Firebug, Chrome Dev Tool to check memory leak in Javascript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only thing in your code that allocates memory is the new function you attach to the on click event.

there is no memory leak, however it could cause high memory usage if you create millions of elements dynamically, and call this function for each of them.

otherwise, this function will not cause memory leak not by itself.

Answer (score 1):

In today's browsers there is no memory leak. However, in older IE versions, this code produced a leak indeed.

A memory leak occurs if the garbage collector cannot remove an object because it is still referenced somewhere. Early garbage collectors had problems with cyclic references, i.e. when an object A refers to an object B and vice versa.

That's the case here in older IE versions: `el` has a reference to the function because the function is set as its value for the `onclick` property (that should be obvious).
But the function also has a reference to `el` because it is a closure that closes over `el`. That's the cyclic reference.